# Как соотнести индекс массива со свойством объекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет. На бэкэнде хранится массив с объектами

```
[
{
"id": 0,
"imageUrl": "https://thumb.tildacdn.com/tild3132-3935-4530-b137-396535386334/-/format/webp/amsterdam_pie_1.jpg",
"title": "Амстердамский пирог",
"sizes": [
300,
600,
900
],
"price": 295,
"category": 1,
"rating": 4
},
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как соотнести свойства объекта "title", "price", "rating" с индексом массива list?

```
function Sort() {
  const { selectedSort, setSelectedSort } = useContext(Context);
  const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState(false);
  const list = ['По популярности', 'По цене', 'По названию'];
  const onClickSort = (i) => {
    setSelectedSort(i);
    setOpenPopup(false);
  };
```

Это нужно для сортировки элементов на странице.

[image: popup]

Запрос выглядит так:

```
fetch(
      `https://636f5291f2ed5cb047daa480.mockapi.io/items?${
        active > 0 ? `category=${active}` : ''
      }&sortBy=${selectedSort}&order=asc`,
    )
```

Т.о. задача сделать так, чтобы браузер понял, что при клике на тип сортировки "по цене", в fetch добавлялся id=1 и свойство "price".

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте справочник, которым можно будет пользоваться для преобразования значений.

Т.к. не известно, что где у вас подставляется и что передается, то вот варианты соотношения значений на клиенте значениям на сервере:

Создать объект, где ключ ключ имя "на клиенте", а значение имя "на сервере"

```
const combo = {
  'По популярности': 'rating',
  'По цене': 'price',
  'По названию': 'title'
}
```

Получать значение для сервер `combo[clientName]`

Такой же справочник, только не по имени, а по индексу

```
const comboIndex = {
  0: 'rating',
  1: 'price',
  2: 'title'
}
```

Получить данные для сервера можно так `comboIndex[index]`

Справочник массив массивов. По индексу можно получить и имя для клиента и имя для сервера

```
const listData = [['По популярности', 'rating'], ['По цене', 'price'], ['По названию', 'title']];
```

`listData[index][0]` - Клиенту, `listData[index][1]` - серверу

Справочник - массив значений

```
const listValue = [{name: 'По популярности', value: 'rating'}, {name: 'По цене', value: 'price'}, {name: 'По названию', value: 'title'}];
```

Для клиента `listValue[index].name`, для сервера `listValue[index].value`